# Change wifi router password of TPlink TD-W8951ND

Tags: wireless-router, adsl-router, adsl2+

Recently, I found out that someone changed my router's default password. So, I have not been able to log into the router setting of my TPlink. While opening, 192.168.1.1 , it asks for password, and while I tried to log in through my old username and password, still I have not been able to get it through. I even tried to reset my router, but to no avail. Please help me through this.

Comment: When you say that you've tried a reset, do you mean a "hard reset" (restoring factory settings)?

Comment: No, I just touched the reset button

Comment: [Your router manual](http://exewiki.exetel.com.au/index.php?title=TP-Link_TD-W8951ND_User_Guide)